# How can I create a $watch function that listens for a nested property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a function property that triggers when I drag a `div` box (gridster). The function fires no problem as I can see it every time in the console.log(). But I can't seem to put a `$watch`er on the function. I want to watch either the `start`, `drag`, and/or `stop` property whenever it is called in the following object:

```
$scope.gridsterOpts = {
    draggable: {
        start: function(event, $element, widget) {console.log('started: ' + JSON.stringify(widget));},  
        drag: function(event, $element, widget) {console.log('moved: ' + JSON.stringify(widget));}, // optional callback fired when item is moved,
        stop: function(event, $element, widget) {logWidget(widget);}  
    }
}
```

This is what I've tried:

```
$scope.$watch("gridsterOpts.draggable.start", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('gridsterOpts changed')
}, true);
```

Can someone tell me the correct way to implement the $watch service?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The `$watch` listener function will only trigger when `$scope.gridsterOpts.draggable.start` value changes. The `$watch` listener won't fire when you call the function.

Comment: that explains why the console.log isn't showing, is there away to trigger the watch service when the function is simply called?

Comment: You are using `angular-gridster`? Right?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there is a way to do it without `$watch`.

Comment: @KO12 Like georgeawg, I also think you don't need `$watch` as you can do the job in the respective function. Can you tell us what you want to do in `$watch` listener function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {return $scope.gridsterOpts.draggable.start}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log('gridsterOpts changed')
        }, true);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the $ on the scope

Comment: can you try again with $scope inside the return instead of plain scope?

Comment: I tried and didn't do anything. The watch service you've suggested will only trigger if the function itself has changed, not when it's called. I need it to trigger when the function is called.